# How to allow parameters/argument with "." (dot) in cakePHP auth component?

Tags: php, cakephp

> http://domainname.com/mains/index/05.01

in the above url, auth component(in cakePHP) not allowing the parameter "05.01" as it contains the dot.
Then how to solve this problem? Please help me to get out of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be helpful to you.

Write this code into your routes.php
In this code I have written regular expression for the passing parameter validation. It means the parameter should contains only given characters.

```
Router::connect('/:slug', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'publicProfile'), array('pass' => array('slug'), 'slug' => '[.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'));
```